# Data Cleanup: Eliminating values contained in csv file from result

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, data-cleaning

I want my final data to not have elements of the initial test data which I want to clean up. The process of copying and pasting data in the code has been extremely tedious and gets complicated as more and more criteria is added.

**Original Values**:

```
(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4),  (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5)
(1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4),  (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)
```

I want a combination which excludes the combinations contained in **Test.csv**

```
(1,2,3),   (2,3,4),     (3,4,5),
```

**Expected Values**

```
(1, 2, 4),
(1, 2, 5),
(1, 3, 4),
(1, 3, 5),
(1, 4, 5),
(2, 3, 5),
(2, 4, 5)
```

**Code Attempt 1**

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

import csv

with open('Test.csv', newline='') as myFile:  
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    list_a = list(reader)

combo_a = [(p,q,r) for p in a for q in a for r in a
                 if q > p and r > q and r > p
                 and (p,q,r) not in list_a]

print (combo_a)
```

**Code Attempt 2**

```
 a = [1,2,3,4,5]

import csv

with open('Test.csv', newline='') as myFile:  
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    list_a = list(map(tuple, reader))

combo_a = [(p,q,r) for p in a for q in a for r in a
                 if q > p and r > q and r > p
                 and (p,q,r) not in list_a]

print (combo_a)
```

**Both Codes output Incorrect Result**

```
(1, 2, 3),
(1, 2, 4),
(1, 2, 5),
(1, 3, 4),
(1, 3, 5),
(1, 4, 5),
(2, 3, 4),
(2, 3, 5),
(2, 4, 5),
(3, 4, 5),
```

Comment: Did you try to *unwind* the list comprehensions into a regular for loop? It might be easier to *see* the problem.

Comment: Have you looked at what `list_a` is after `list(map(tuple, reader))`? I'm not totally sure that it's giving you what you are looking for

Comment: This is the output of list_a  [('1', '2', '3'), ('2', '3', '4'), ('3', '4', '5')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `list_a` is a tuple of strings, not integers. So if your

```
list_a = [('1', '2', '3'), ('2', '3', '4'), ('3', '4', '5')]
```

Then convert it into integers using

```
list_a = [tuple(map(int, i)) for i in list_a]
```

Once it is in the form of a list of integer tuples then you can proceed with your `combo_a` operation.

Comment: List is generally in a column as below. How will converting into integers help? Please elaborate.                                                                                
                                             (1,2,3),                                                                        
                                             (2,3,4),                                                                        
                                             (3,4,5),

Comment: Your list seems to be tuples of strings, not integers and you are using `(p,q,r) not in list_a` for comparison where `p,q,r` are integers whereas they are strings in `list_a`. So (1,2,3) will not in [('1','2','3')]. So one solution is to convert it into list to of integer tuples before doing the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

With contents of the **`file.csv`**:

```
(1,2,3),   (2,3,4),     (3,4,5),
```

and using `csv` and `ast.literal_eval`:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

import csv
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import combinations

excluded = set()
with open('file.csv', newline='') as myFile:
    reader = csv.reader(myFile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        l = list(map(literal_eval, [val for val in row if val]))
        excluded.update(tuple(i[0]) for i in l)

print(',\n'.join(map(str, sorted(set(combinations(a, 3)) - excluded))))
```

Prints:

```
(1, 2, 4),
(1, 2, 5),
(1, 3, 4),
(1, 3, 5),
(1, 4, 5),
(2, 3, 5),
(2, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to filter specific values?

What I would do is keep a list with the values you don't want. After that just check if the tuples you are filter are in the list.

So load all values from test.csv into your list.

```py
dont_want = [some set of tuples you dont want]


combo_a = [(p,q,r) for p in a for q in a for r in a
                 if (p,q,r) not in dont_want]
```

Forgive me if I misinterpreted your problem but I think I know what you're asking.

Comment: Yes I am. I have done precisely that and it throws the incorrect result. Is there something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you aren't actually processing `int`'s, you are processing lists of strings, because the tuples are comma delimited along with the entries themselves:

```py
from io import StringIO
import csv

c = """(1,2,3),   (2,3,4),     (3,4,5),"""

fh = StringIO(c, newline='')

reader = csv.reader(fh)
next(reader)

# ['(1', '2', '3)', '   (2', '3', '4)', '     (3', '4', '5)', '']
```

This is not a list of tuples, so to get it to be one:

```py
import ast
from io import StringIO # this simulates your file handle

fh = StringIO(c, newline='')

# it's only one line, so call next(fh)
lst = ast.literal_eval(f"[{next(fh)}]")

# [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```

Where `ast` will process them into their native data structures. Translated into your code:

```py
import ast

with open('Test.csv', newline='') as fh:
    list_a = ast.literal_eval(f"[{next(fh)}]")
```

Now `list_a` is a list of tuples of integers. Then you can just exclude ones in the list:

```py
from itertools import combinations

checked = set()

for c in combinations(list(range(1,6)), 3):
    a = tuple(sorted(c))
    if a not in list_a and a not in checked:
        print(a)
        checked.add(a)
```